# Cache is being stored after second refresh

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

After my service worker got registered, On second reload I am able to cache the response which I want to do without second refresh ,

I am using Workbox version 3 , 
Even after using workbox.core.skipWaiting and workbox.core.clientsClaim , I am not able to cache my data, I am new to Progressive web app and service worker, Any help will we appreciated , Below is my code snippets for the service worker -

Even after using workbox.core.skipWaiting and workbox.core.clientsClaim , I am not able to cache my data on loading for the first time-

My service worker -

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('My URL from where I want to cache the response'),
    new workbox.core.skipWaiting(),
    new workbox.core.clientsClaims(),
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()

);
```

My worlnox-config file -

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "build/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{json,ico,html,js,css}"
  ],
  "swDest": "./build/sw.js",
  "swSrc" : "./src/sworker.js"
};
```

On loading the page I want to cache my API response without reloading.

Answer (score 1):

This is how service workers behave. The service worker is installing but not read as the other assets are being downloaded and rendered so there is no way for the service worker it handle and cache the resources. If you want the assets to be cached without a subsequent navigation you'll want to [tell Workbox to precache](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching) the assets. This will tell the service worker to to download and cache the assets after being installed without the client asking any additional requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response @abraham ,But my API response is getting cached after I reload the page which I don't want in my case